# sweetalert2 вывод данных переменной

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, popup, sweetalert

Имеется проект в котором использовались формы bootstrap 3.

Нужно переделать под sweetalert2.
Вопрос как выводить данные в код sweetalert2, данных переменной?
Что бы не писать огромные участки кода через

```
html:
'You can use <b>bold text</b>, ' +
'<a href="//sweetalert2.github.io">links</a> ' +
```

Конструкция сейчас следующая:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.user-email').on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest('.popup-regstration-buttons').slideToggle();
  $('form[name=form-users-register]').slideToggle();

  return false;
 });

 $('form[name=form-users-forget]').submit(function() {
  $.post('/login/forget/save', {user_email: $(this).find('input').val(), }, function(r) {
   $('.modal-content').html(r);
  })
  return false;
 });

    $('form[name=form-users-login]').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'Проверьте форму на наличие ошибок',
  feedbackIcons: {
   valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
   invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
   validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
  },
  submitButtons: 'input[type=submit]',
  submitHandler: null,
  live: 'enabled',
        fields: {
         'login': {
             enabled: true,
    validators: {
     notEmpty: {
      message: '<div class="login__error">Введите e-mail<div>'
     },
     emailAddress: {
      message: '<div class="login__error">Указан неверный адрес почты<div>'
     }
    }
   },
   'password': {
             enabled: true,
    validators: {
     notEmpty: {
      message: '<div class="login__error">Введите пароль</div>'
     }
    }
   }
        }
    });

    $('form[name=form-users-forget]').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'Проверьте форму на наличие ошибок',
  feedbackIcons: {
   valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
   invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
   validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
  },
  submitButtons: 'input[type=submit]',
  submitHandler: null,
  live: 'enabled',
        fields: {
         'user_email': {
             enabled: true,
    validators: {
     notEmpty: {
      message: '<div class="login__error">Введите e-mail</div>'
     },
     emailAddress: {
      message: '<div class="login__error">Указан неверный адрес почты</div>'
     }
    }
   },
        }
    });

 {% if login_data|length %}
 $('form[name=form-users-login]').submit();
 {% endif %}
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- end cdn css -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- end cdn js -->

<div class="login-box">
  <div class="login-logo">
    <a href="/"><b>Новый</b>Проект</a>
  </div>
  <!-- /.login-logo -->
  <div class="card">
    <li class="Login_exit"><a href="{{ frontend }}/login" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Эта кнопка вызывает старый попап (и в нем генерируется контент)</a></li>
    <div class="card-body login-card-body">
      <p class="login-box-msg">Зарегистрируйтесь сейчас</p>


      <form action="{{ app }}login-2/process2" method="POST" name="form-users-login" class="slide-form">
        <div class="input-group mb-3 popup-regstration-form form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="login" value="{{ login_data.login }}" placeholder="Email">
          <span name="login__error"></span>
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group form-group mb-3">
          <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-8">
            <div class="icheck-primary">
              <input type="checkbox" id="remember">
              <label for="remember">
                Запомните меня
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-4">
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="form-users-login-submit" value="Войти">
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
        <!-- кнопки управления -->
        <p class="mb-1">
          <a href="#" onclick="$('.slide-form').slideToggle(); return true;">Забыли пароль?</a>
        </p>
        <p class="mb-0">
          <a href="register.html" class="text-center">Зарегистрироваться сейчас</a>
        </p>
      </form>

      <!-- форма восстановления пароля -->
      <form action="{{ app }}login/forget/save" method="POST" name="form-users-forget" style="display:none" class="slide-form">
        <div class="popup-forget-form">
        <div class="input-group mb-3 form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_email" value="" placeholder="E-mail">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <div class="icheck-primary">
              <a href="#" onclick="$('.slide-form').slideToggle(); return true;" class="btn btn-block btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Отменить</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-8">
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="form-users-login-submit" value="Сменить пароль">
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.login-card-body -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.login-box -->



<!-- код модального окна который находиться у меня в index.tpl -->
<!-- сюда и транслируются данные -->



          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Загрузка..</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="te"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Как мне реализовать вставку этой формы в sweetalert2? Ниже код его дефолтного попапа.

```js
<script>
  $(document).on('click', '#fire', function(e) {
Swal.fire({
  title: '<strong>HTML <u>example</u></strong>',
  type: 'info',
  html:
    'You can use <b>bold text</b>, ' +
    '<a href="//sweetalert2.github.io">links</a> ' +
    'and other HTML tags',
  showCloseButton: true,
  showCancelButton: true,
  focusConfirm: false,
  confirmButtonText:
    '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Great!',
  confirmButtonAriaLabel: 'Thumbs up, great!',
  cancelButtonText:
    '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>',
  cancelButtonAriaLabel: 'Thumbs down',

})
  });
    </script>
```

Если, сформулировано не правильно, буду рад критике и исправлю ошибки. Спасибо

Comment: Вы хотите использовал swal как модальное окно? Или вы хотите встраивать переменные в строку которую выводите в swal? не совсем понятен вопрос

Comment: Если вы хотите встраивать переменные в строку максимально удобно, используйте интерполяцию `lorem ipsum ${var} lorem ipsum`, просто пишите все в наклонных кавычках `

Comment: Здравствуйте, благодарю за ответ!
Я хочу использовать swal как модальное окно (с выводом уже моей созданной разметки) если такое возможно,
"Если вы хотите встраивать переменные в строку" - узнать это было не менее полезно, спасибо